# CodeIgniter .htaccess file permission error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|table-images|js|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wholesale/index.php/$1 [L]
```

I cannot view `images/` and `css/`. When I look at the source and follow the link , I can see there is a message that you do not have permison to view this file.

Comment: can you access it directly without the htaccess file? if so it might be a file permission problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a given sometimes, but I want to address it anyway. Make sure your `.htaccess` file has been uploaded to your hosting service. If it's not uploading properly, try again, contact the support department of your hosting service for assistance, or try to (if you're feeling dangerous) manually edit your `.htaccess` directly from the Server/FTP.

Also, when using CodeIgniter, the `.htaccess` setup can be different from hosting service to hosting service. Most hosting services (I know for sure GoDaddy and Hostmonster do this) have their on wikis on how to do this properly for their specific service.

For more information on `.htaccess` information for CodeIgniter, check out the following link.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

I hope this helps. If it doesn't, post any more information or error messages that occur during the process of trying to solve the issue with the information given, and I'll see if I can help futher. Good luck!